# difference between collection route and member route in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the difference between collection routes and member routes in Rails?

For example,

```
resources :photos do
  member do
    get :preview
  end
end
```

versus

```
resources :photos do
  collection do
    get :search
  end
end
```

I don't understand.

Answer (score 444, accepted):

A member route will require an ID, because it acts on a *member*. A collection route doesn't because it acts on a collection of objects. Preview is an example of a member route, because it acts on (and displays) a single object. Search is an example of a collection route, because it acts on (and displays) a collection of objects.

Comment: What about the create action? Say I wanted to make an alternative to 'create' - would it count as a member?

Comment: Yes, create is a member action.

Comment: But what about adding a "get" without any block? Is it member or collection route? My test showed its collection but with different id variable name.

Comment: Are you sure about create being a member action. There is no ID to pass.

Comment: @GeorgeShaw The Id u're wondering about will be nested in the url u are sending to the create-action. Let's say that u have a resources called 'posts' and u've a member called 'vote' nested inside resources :posts; of course. Then u wanna create something like a vote; u wanna a vote on a certain post. U'll be sending to the create-action of vote  something like this: 'posts/:id/vote'; comprende? and there u've yr ID u're wondering about :) I hope this helps...(...)

Comment: @YoniGeek. Not correct. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, 2.7 Nested Resources. Create is always a collection action as you are adding to the collection. Note that the named create path is always plural. In your example you are adding a new vote to the collection of votes that belong to a member of posts. The id refers to the member post, not the collection of votes being created.The named path would be posts_votes_url, for example.

Comment: @Theo How to give action to the given member/collection of resource.  I didn't find on net. Although I can ask it as separate question but I think one will get the answer from the comment section... so. please.

Comment: @zeal This is three years late, but the action is given after the verb. In the examples above, the actions would be "preview" and "search".

Answer (score 239):

```
                URL                 Helper                      Description
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
member          /photos/1/preview   preview_photo_path(photo)   Acts on a specific resource so required id (preview specific photo)
collection      /photos/search      search_photos_path          Acts on collection of resources(display all photos)
```

Comment: Should use `search_photos_path` instead of `search_photos_url` so people won't think `_path` and `_url` are a difference between the two.

Answer (score 36):

Theo's answer is correct. For documentation's sake, I'd like to also note that the two will generate different path helpers.

`member {get 'preview'}` will generate:

```
preview_photo_path(@photo) # /photos/1/preview
```

`collection {get 'search'}` will generate:

```
search_photos_path # /photos/search
```

Note plurality!

Answer (score 15):

1)  **:collection** - Add named routes for other actions that operate on the collection. Takes a hash of `#{action} => #{method}`, where method is `:get/:post/:put/:delete`, an array of any of the previous, or :any if the method does not matter. These routes map to a URL like **/users/customers_list**, with a route of **customers_list_users_url**.

> map.resources :users, :collection => { :customers_list=> :get }

2) `:member` - Same as `:collection`, but for actions that operate on a
    specific member.

> map.resources :users, :member => { :inactive=> :post }

it treated as `/users/1;inactive=> [:action => 'inactive', :id => 1]`

Comment: nice example. explanation at the top could have been better though.

Answer (score 1):

#### Short Answer:

Both the `member` and `collection` blocks allow you to define additional routes for your resources than the seven standard routes that Rails will generate for you.

- A `member` block creates new routes on a single member of the resource.
- A `collection` block creates new routes for a collection of that resource.

---

#### Long Answer

Rails provides the `member` and `collection` blocks so you can define custom routes for both the resource collection and the individual resource.

Here's how you'd typically define routes for the article resource.

```rb
resources :articles
```

This creates the following routes.

```bash
➜ bin/rails routes -g article

      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
    articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
             POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
 new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
     article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
             PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
```

But let's say you are writing your articles in markdown, and need to see a preview of the article as you write it.

You could create a `PreviewController` and display the article's preview using its `show` action, but it's convenient to add a preview action on the `ArticlesController` itself.

#### Custom Member Routes

Here's how you define the preview route on the `ArticlesController` using the member block.

```rb
resources :articles do
  member do
    get 'preview'
  end
end
```

It adds a new route that directs the request to `ArticlesController#preview` action. The remaining routes remain unchanged. It also passes the article id in `params[:id]` and creates the `preview_article_path` and `preview_article_url` helpers.

```bash
➜ bin/rails routes -g article

         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
preview_article GET    /articles/:id/preview(.:format) articles#preview

... remaining routes
```

If you have a single member route, use the short-hand version by passing the `:on` option to the route, eliminating the block.

```rb
resources :articles do
  get 'preview', on: :member
end
```

You can go one step further and leave out the `:on` option.

```rb
resources :articles do
  get 'preview'
end
```

It generates the following route.

```bash
➜  bin/rails routes -g preview

         Prefix Verb URI Pattern                         Controller#Action       
article_preview GET  /articles/:article_id/preview(.:format) articles#preview
```

There are two important differences here:

1. The article's id is available as `params[:article_id]` instead of `params[:id]`.
2. The route helpers changes from `preview_article_path` to `article_preview_path` and `preview_article_url` to `article_preview_url`.

#### Custom Collection Routes

To add a new route for the collection of a resource, use the collection block.

```rb
resources :articles do
  collection do
    get 'search'
  end
end
```

This adds the following new route. It will also add a `search_articles_path` and `search_articles_url` helper.

```bash
search_articles GET    /articles/search(.:format)   articles#search
```

If you don't need multiple `collection` routes, just pass `:on` option to the route.

```rb
resources :articles do
  get 'search', on: :collection
end
```

This will add the same route as above.

#### Conclusion

Rails allows you to break out of its convention of using seven resourceful routes using the `member` and `collection` blocks. Both allow you to define additional routes for your resources than the standard seven routes.

A `member` block acts on a single member of the resource, whereas a `collection` operates on a collection of that resource.

Source: [Define New Routes Using the Member and Collection Blocks](https://www.akshaykhot.com/define-new-routes-using-member-and-collection-blocks-in-rails/)