# Create a simple route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, custom-routes

I am having problems create the right route. I want to pass in the id of the element that i am working on but it does not look right.

my route looks like

```
resources :accounts
  match 'account-audit' => 'accounts#audited',:as => :accountaudit
```

and when i do rake routes i get

```
          accounts GET    /accounts(.:format)                          accounts#index
                   POST   /accounts(.:format)                          accounts#create
       new_account GET    /accounts/new(.:format)                      accounts#new
      edit_account GET    /accounts/:id/edit(.:format)                 accounts#edit
           account GET    /accounts/:id(.:format)                      accounts#show
                   PUT    /accounts/:id(.:format)                      accounts#update
                   DELETE /accounts/:id(.:format)                      accounts#destroy
      accountaudit        /account-audit(.:format)                     accounts#audited
```

when i go to the page the link looks

> localhost:3000/account-audit.3

and it should look like

> localhost:3000/account/3/audit

how do i make my route do what i need it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it looks like you are trying to do is a nested routes this will give you the restful routes for audit inside of accounts

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :audit
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare routes like this

```
resources :accounts do
  get :audit, on: :member, as: :accountaudit
end
```

This will generate links like `localhost:3000/accounts/account_id/audit`. Check [this stackoverlfow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028653/difference-between-collection-route-and-member-route-in-ruby-on-rails) to learn about member and collection routes.

Comment: i ma sure that works but i ended up using 
`match '/account/:id/audit' => 'accounts#audited',:as => :accountaudit`