# Create action to change boolean value in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, methods, controller, routes, link-to

I have a simple model for suggestions in my Rails 3 application. I am trying to add a simple link_to link on the index view that when clicked marks the suggestion as approved.

So far I have the following code:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :suggestions do
 get :approve
end
```

**suggestions_controller.rb**

```
def approve
 @suggestion = Suggestion.find(params[:id])
 @suggestion.update_attribute(:approved, 'true')
 @suggestion.update_attribute(:approved_on, Time.now)
 redirect_to suggestion_path
end
```

**suggestion.rb**

```
attr_accessible :author, :details, :localip, :title, :approved, :approved_on
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "suggestions", :force => true do |t|
 t.string   "title"
 t.string   "author"
 t.text     "details"
 t.string   "localip"
 t.datetime "created_at",                     :null => false
 t.datetime "updated_at",                     :null => false
 t.boolean  "approved",    :default => false
 t.datetime "approved_on"
end
```

**index.html.erb (suggestions)**

```
<% if @suggestion.approved? %>
    <%= @suggestion.approved_on %>
<% else %>
    Not yet approved. (<%= link_to "Approve", approve_suggestion_url(@approve), :method => :put %>)
<% end %>
```

When using the above code, I get the following exception error:

```
undefined method `approved?' for nil:NilClass
```

Am I missing a step out somewhere something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, the code you have posted is inside an each loop like

```
<% @suggestions.each do |suggestion| %>
  ...
  <% if @suggestion.approved? %>
    <%= @suggestion.approved_on %>
  <% else %>
    Not yet approved. (<%= link_to "Approve", approve_suggestion_url(@approve), :method => :put %>)
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You need to use `suggestion` variable instead of `@suggestion` instance variable. Also, to construct suggestion approve url, you'll need to use `suggestion` instead of `@approve`. Code should be like

```
  <% if suggestion.approved? %>
    <%= suggestion.approved_on %>
  <% else %>
    Not yet approved. (<%= link_to "Approve", approve_suggestion_url(suggestion), :method => :put %>)
  <% end %>
```

Also, you should modify your routes.rb to reflect that `approve` action is a member action.

```
resources :suggestions do
  put :approve, on: :member
end
```

To understand the difference between member and collection routes, read [difference between collection route and member route in ruby on rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028653/difference-between-collection-route-and-member-route-in-ruby-on-rails).

Comment: Ahh thanks, stupid mistake to make! I seem to get a routing error though `No route matches [PUT] "/suggestions/8/approve"`

Comment: If you want to keep method as put in link generation, then modify routes.rb as `put :approve, on: :member`.