# Rails routes: GET without param :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I'm developing a REST API based on rails. To use this API, you MUST be logged in. Regarding that, I'd like to create a method `me` in my user controller that will return a JSON of the logged in user infos.
So, I don't need an `:id` to be passed in the URL. I just want to call `http://example.com/api/users/me`

So I tried this:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
  scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
    resources :tokens, :only => [:create, :destroy]
    resources :users, :only => [:index, :update] do

      # I tried this
      match 'me', :via => :get
      # => api_user_me GET    /api/users/:user_id/me(.:format)       api/v1/users#me {:format=>"json"}

      # Then I tried this
      member do
        get 'me'
      end
      # => me_api_user GET    /api/users/:id/me(.:format)            api/v1/users#me {:format=>"json"}

    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, my route waits for an id, but I'd like to get something like devise has. Something based on `current_user` id. Example below:

```
edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
```

In this example you can edit the current user password without passing the id as a param.

I could use a collection instead of a member, but that's a dirty bypass.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Resource routes are designed to work this way. If you want something different, design it yourself, like this.

```
match 'users/me' => 'users#me', :via => :get
```

Put it outside of your `resources :users` block

Comment: Brilliant Arjan. Exactly what I needed... except that I won't have path but I can do without it. Cheers.

Comment: No problem, you could add a path by adding `:as => 'me'`. This will add `me_path` and `me_url`.

Comment: Consider using singular resources as the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25642181/2057928)

Answer (score 126):

The way to go is to use [singular resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources):

So, instead of `resources` use `resource`:

> Sometimes, you have a resource that clients always look up without referencing an ID. For example, you would like /profile to always show the profile of the currently logged in user. In this case, you can use a singular resource to map /profile (rather than /profile/:id) to the show action [...]

So, in your case:

```
resource :user do
  get :me, on: :member
end

# => me_api_user GET    /api/users/me(.:format)            api/v1/users#me {:format=>"json"}
```

Comment: This should be accepted. While `get 'users/me' => 'users#me'` works well enough, grouping them as a singular resource is a cleaner approach.

Comment: Just make sure you pay attention to the red box mentioning a long standing bug regarding singular resources. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1769

Comment: I think if you had defined the `resources` then adding to the `collection` would be a better (as some of the other answers have pointed out). Adding a singular resource will work but I think it would make more sense and be more readable to keep it all together

Comment: CAUTION: one should either use the singular ```resource``` or the plural ```resources``` but not combine them, otherwise only the first occurrence will be routed to.

Answer (score 22):

You can use

```
resources :users, only: [:index, :update] do
  get :me, on: :collection
end
```

or

```
resources :users, only: [:index, :update] do
  collection do
    get :me
  end
end
```

"A member route will require an ID, because it acts on a member. A collection route doesn't because it acts on a collection of objects. Preview is an example of a member route, because it acts on (and displays) a single object. Search is an example of a collection route, because it acts on (and displays) a collection of objects." (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028653/difference-between-collection-route-and-member-route-in-ruby-on-rails/%22here%22))

Answer (score 14):

Maybe I am missing something, but why don't you use:

```
get 'me', on: :collection
```

Comment: That's what I said in my conclusion. It's not a nice work around since a collection is an array of multiple object. I'm asking for the current_user, so 1 object, so a member ;-)

Answer (score 7):

```
  resources :users, only: [:index, :update] do
    collection do
      get :me, action: 'show' 
    end
  end
```

specifying the action is optional. you can skip action here and name your controller action as `me`.

Answer (score 3):

This gives same result as Arjan's in simpler way

`get 'users/me', to: 'users#me'`

Answer (score 0):

When you create a route nested within a resource, you can mention, whether it is member action or a collection action.

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
  scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
    resources :tokens, :only => [:create, :destroy]
    resources :users, :only => [:index, :update] do

      # I tried this
      match 'me', :via => :get, :collection => true
...
...
```

Comment: That's what I said in my conclusion. It's not a nice work around since a collection is an array of multiple object. I'm asking for the current_user, so 1 object, so a member ;-)