# how to hide "id" in url using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

```
controller.rb

@user = User.where(:id => params[:id]).take

html.erb

<a href="/home/layout02_03/<%=@interest.id%>">
 something
</a>
```

click that a tag then url is "/home/layout02_03/3"

3 is user's id,

but I don't want to expose that "id"

how can I do that, I'm using ruby on rails

Comment: I would change your route. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066637/rails-routes-get-without-param-id

Answer (score 2):

You need to have any other unique attribute on the User model, e.g. some random GUID value, once you have it, just use it instead of the ID:

```
<a href="/home/layout02_03/<%= @interest.obscure_uniq_identifier %>">
```

Or define it to be the default URL representation for the User:

```
class User

def to_param
  obscure_uniq_identifier
end
```

You can generate one using:

```
before_create :generate_guid
def generate_guid
  self.obscure_uniq_identifier = SecureRandom.hex
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is having the same issue, I would also suggest you to use a gem like [Visibilize](https://github.com/FEApaydin/visibilize) which offers more options on creating exposable friendly ID's.

Just install the gem and call `visibilize` inside your model.