# Alternate route to `create` - route without id fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Need to have alternate route to `create` must work both:

```
POST /users
POST /users/new
```

There recomendation from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066637/rails-routes-get-without-param-id) how to add route without id:

```
resource :user do
  get :me, on: :member
end
```

Need not `user` but `users`:

```
resources :users do                                                                                                           
  post :new, on: :create                                                                                                        
end
```

crash message:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `on' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x0000081022c8c0\>

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
resources :users do
  post :new, on: :collection
end
```

You need to specify the HTTP verb, action and the target. If the target is `:member`, then Rails expects an "id" parameter and constructs the URL based on that.

Make sure to read this [guide on Rails routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).