# Ruby on Rails 4: Display Search Results on Search Results Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently implementing the search functionality in a project and I am struggling displaying it on a dedicated search result page.

Being aware of questions on this topic already but being unable to work out a solution due to utter incompetence, I am asking you for the final pointer :).

The search form spawns on the index page which is entries_path and root_path. I'd like to pass on the parameters to a new page, search_path.

Here are my files:

**EntriesController**

```
def search
end

def index
  @entries = Entry.all.order('entries.created_at DESC')
  @entry = Entry.new # My index page also creates new entries.

  if params[:search]
    @entries = Entry.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @entries = Entry.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end
```

**Model: entry.rb**

```
def self.search(search)
  where("content LIKE ? OR created_at LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%") 
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :entries 
  root                  'entries#index'  
  get   'new'       =>  'entries/new'
  get   'show'      =>  'entries/show'
  get   'edit'      =>  'entries/edit'
  get   'search'    =>  'entries/search'
```

**Finally: the form on index**

```
<%= form_tag(entries_path, :method => "get", class: "search-form") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search for previous entries..", class: "form-control" %>
<% end %>
```

When I change the entries_path to search_path, I am getting a "We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information." – therefore, I suspect it is a routing problem. However, I can't seem to figure it out. The log says:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Entries):
```

Phew, would love to know what's going on here! Thanks a bunch already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your **routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root                  'entries#index'
  resources :entries  do
    collection do
      get :search
    end
  end
end
```

change your `path` in `search` form on **index** page:

```
<%= form_tag(search_entries_path, :method => :get, class: "search-form") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search for previous entries..", class: "form-control" %>
<% end %>
```

Change your controller's method:

```
def search
  if params[:search]
    @entries = Entry.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @entries = Entry.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end
end
```

create one template for search method under **`view/entries/search.html.erb`**
You can here access your **`@entries`** object

---

Points of changes I have made:

### 1. Changes in **routes.rb**:

Rails router recognizes URLs and dispatches them to a controller's action. It can also generate `paths` and `URLs`, avoiding the need to hardcode strings in your views.
A `resource` route maps a number of related requests to actions in a **single controller**. a resourceful route provides a mapping between `HTTP verbs` and `URLs` to controller actions. By **convention**, each action also maps to particular **`CRUD`** operations in a database. for [more information regarding routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web)

You can add additional routes that apply to the `collection` or `individual members of the collection`.

For Eg:

To add a **member route**, just add a member block into the resource block:

```
resources :entries do
  member do
    get 'preview'
  end
end
```

To add a route to the **collection**:

```
resources :entries do
  collection do
    get 'search'
  end
end
```

A **member route** will require an `ID`, because it acts on a `member`. A **collection route** doesn't because it acts on a `collection` of `objects`. for more info about 
[difference between collection route and member route in ruby on rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028653/difference-between-collection-route-and-member-route-in-ruby-on-rails)

### 2. Which method should I use for search `GET` or `POST`?

There are numbers of post available regarding `GET` and `POST` request on the web as well as SO. `GET` and `POST` both have their place, and if you’re a Web developer you should understand the **pros and cons** of each of them. Or if you’re too lazy to do that, just remember that [Search forms should use GET method](http://rc3.org/2007/12/26/search-forms-should-use-the-get-method/). Your users will appreciate it. ;)

Let me define them in short description.
`GET` to fetch a resource(when you don't want to make any change in your DB), `POST` to create a resource(when you want to make a change/create in your DB), `PUT` (or `PATCH`, these is debate on the matter) to update a resource, `DELETE` to delete one.

For your reference:

- [When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)

**I hope this information may helps you. Good Luck :)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use html as a search field on Index page.

```
<form>
  <legend>Search</legend>
  <div class='col-xs-4'>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' value='<%= params[:search] %>' name='keyword' placeholder='Keyword' >
  </div>
</form>
```

Note: This form would hit your index action of entries controller, So at this point no need to create a `search methods` as you have created