# resource is no need member or collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know `member` and `collection` is not same for `resources`.
but how about for `resource`. Are you use `member` and `collection` for `resource`?.

I found

```
resource :foo do
  patch :confirm
end
```

and

```
resource :foo do
  member do
    patch :confirm
  end
end
```

and

```
resource :foo do
  collection do
    patch :confirm
  end
end
```

are Same.

Route => /foo/confirm(.:format)
Method => PATCH
Action => FoosController#confirm
Name => confirm_foo

No document for `resource block`, only about `resources block`.
[Rails Routing from the Outside In — Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

`resource` use no `member` or `collection` is collect way?
`member` or `collection` or no use these, which is best practice?

Comment: The  `resource` method [is well documented](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) read it carefully.

Comment: yes. but not say member and collection.

Comment: It's unclear for me what you asking. _is correct way?_ Which way? You can use what you want, it's totally depend on your application logic, for what is `confirm` action used for `member` or `collection`?. `member` for member, `collection` for collection.

Comment: I wont to add custom route for `Singular Resources`. There are many way.
also `patch 'confirm', to: : confirm, controller: 'foos'`. I want to know how to use `resource block`. only `resources block` documented.

Comment: `member` and `collection` for `resources` is different. but I think these are same behavior for `resource`.

Answer (score 1):

Member and collection are not the same.

A member route will require an ID, because it acts on a member.

`foo/:id/confirm`

A collection route doesn't because it acts on a collection of objects.

`foo/confirm`

Similar: [difference between collection route and member route in ruby on rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028653/difference-between-collection-route-and-member-route-in-ruby-on-rails)

Adding more restful actions: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: I think `member` and `collection` for `resources` is not the same. but how about for `resource`.

Comment: Oh I missed that it was singular. Then yes they are all the same. :)