# No matching Route error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am new in Ruby on Rails. I have been trying for two days to define a route for a method in the controller but error shows saying "No route matches [GET]".
Here is the code

```
donations Controller:

before_action :set_donation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :create_user_account]
  before_action :set_campaign, only: [:new, :create_user_account]
//this is the method that i want to call 
  def create_user_account
  end
```

Here is my route file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :donations, except: [:new, :create]
 get 'donations/create_user_account' => 'donations#create_user_account'
  resources :campaigns do
    resources :donations, only: [:new, :create, :create_user_account]
    get 'donations/create_user_account' => 'donations#create_user_account'
  end
  resources :organizations

  devise_for :users

  root to: "campaigns#latest"
end
```

The routes are showing my route name but when i hit the route "no matching" route error occurs.

route1:
    campaign_donations_create_user_account_path GET /campaigns/:campaign_id/donations/create_user_account(.:format) 
    donations#create_user_account
route2:

```
donations_create_user_account_path  GET /donations/create_user_account(.:format)    
donations#create_user_account
```

I want to call route 2 but no route is working

I call my route 2 like this

```
http://localhost:3000/donations/create_uer_account
```

This is the error
[image]

Comment: You are doing it wrong, you should read route types.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028653/difference-between-collection-route-and-member-route-in-ruby-on-rails OR send ID as query parameter in url.

Comment: you are attaching an error related to the typo create_uer_account ...

Comment: @jenvvv edited but same error that is not the problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because this line

```
resources :donations, except: [:new, :create]
```

is before the others in `routes.rb`. Rails matches with the first route it finds in the routes.rb file.

It should look something like this

```
get 'donations/create_user_account' => 'donations#create_user_account'
resources :donations, except: [:new, :create]
```

then Rails matches with your `create_user_account` first.

Comment: after changing the code according to your advice the error is showing

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in DonationsController#create_user_account

Couldn't find Donation with 'id'=

  def set_donation
      "@donation = Donation.find(params[:id])"
    end
Why it is always going inside set_donation method???

Comment: Because you have it declared in a `before_action`

Comment: still the same error and my code is 
 before_action :set_donation, only: [:create_user_account, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

Comment: It's calling `set_donation` with that `before_action`, remove the `create_user_account` from the `before_action`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will bother you in future too. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141773/discussion-between-john-and-iceman).