# Ruby rails change browser url with resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a nested resources:

```
resources :topic do
    resource :fruits, only: [:edit, :update]
end
```

I want the browser url to be `/topic/:topic_id/fruits(.:format)` (without /edit) instead of `/topic/:topic_id/fruits/edit(.:format)`

In my action controller I see I have these routes

```
GET /topic/:topic_id/fruits/edit
fruits#edit

PATCH /topic/:topic_id/fruits/
fruits#update

PUT /topic/:topic_id/fruits/
fruits#update
```

Comment: Why not just put the form on the `show` view if thats the requirement? While you can certainly route `/topic/:topic_id/fruits` to `topics#edit` its quirky and unconventional. The only reason really that the edit action exists in the conventions is to have a separate view with the form.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is called a `member route` and it is well explained here
[difference between collection route and member route in ruby on rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3028653/9094702)